# How can check that the fast MA stays above the slow MA the next day after crossover?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am very new to Pine Script and need some help writing a MA crossover strategy to backtest.

Scenario: The 50 day SMA crosses over the 100 day SMA, how do I have my strategy also consider if the 50 day SMA remains above the 100 day SMA the following session?

My script so far:

```
start = timestamp (2012,1,1,0,0)
end = timestamp (2022,3,16,0,0)
ma1 = ta.sma(close, 50)
ma2 = ta.sma(close, 100)
plot (sma1, title = "SMA50", color=color.green)
plot (sma2, title = "SMA100", color=color.red)

//strategy
LongEntry = ta.crossover (sma1, sma2)
LongExit = ta.crossover (sma2, sma1)

if time >= start and time < end
    strategy.entry ("Long", strategy.long,1, when = LongEntry)
    strategy.close ("Long", when = LongExit)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need get used to that Pine primary data structure is `Series`. Your script will be run on every bar (or sometimes on ever tick) and on every run there will be a new version of `open`, `close`, your `LongEntry` calculated (and every variable as well).

The singular values (aka. calculation results) of these variables - at the end of your script - will be committed to a `Series` of the same name.

Thus, your `LongEntry` might look like a simple variable, but that has a data type of `Series`. The closest reference to this `Series` type in other programming languages is the `Array`, just its indexing is backwards in Pine, meaning the last/latest entry is at index 0. Thus `LongEntry` is the same as `LongEntry[0]` and you can always leave `[0]` from a variable. `LongEntry[1]` is the previous value of `LongEntry`, `LongEntry[2]` is the second previous value.

Essentially built-in variables work the same, you have `open, open[1], open[2]` as well.

Checking a `crossover` is the same as checking these at the same time:

- variable X is larger than variable Y in the current bar: `X[0] > Y[0]`
- variable X was smaller than variable Y in the previous bar: `X[1] < Y[1]`

If both hold true then X crossed over Y in the current bar.

This is what you want to check:

- a crossover happened in the previous bar (you have your crossover results ie. in LongEntry so this is: `LongEntry[1] = True`)
- and `ma1` is larger than `ma2` in the current bar: `ma1 > ma2`, same as `ma1[0] > ma2[0]`

Summarized: `LongEntry[1] and ma1 > ma2`